# error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, riscv

I am trying to use the GDB debugger using OpenOCD (Ubuntu) for a RISC-V processor running on hardware. I have successfully connected to the RISC-V core with OpenOCD. When I try to run GDB I get the following error message:

---

riscv32-unknown-elf-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory***

I don't know why Python is needed to run this command but I do have Python 3.10 installed on Ubuntu. Do I need Python 3.8 or what is wrong here?

I have checked the GDB toolchain and it is installed correctly.

***EDIT***

I am not very experienced with software involving compilers etc and Ubuntu so I will try add whatever I think may be useful. Or if anyone can advise any way of checking decencies or have any tests I could do to check, let me know.

Below shows trying to run the RISC-V GDB command on Ubuntu, and showing the error message:

```
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/mnt/c/Users/David/.Xilinx/Neorv32_basys3_test_setup_on_chip_debugger/neorv32-main/sw/example/demo_blink_led$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/riscv/bin
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/mnt/c/Users/David/.Xilinx/Neorv32_basys3_test_setup_on_chip_debugger/neorv32-main/sw/example/demo_blink_led$ riscv32-unknown-elf-gdb
riscv32-unknown-elf-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

***IN RESPONSE TO CHARLES DUFFY'S COMMENT***

I think I am in the correct place you are talking about but it seems like it is not there.

```
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/$ ls
bin   etc   lib    libx32      mnt   riscv-openocd                          run   srv  usr
boot  home  lib32  lost+found  opt   riscv32-unknown-elf.gcc-12.1.0.tar.gz  sbin  sys  var
dev   init  lib64  media       proc  root                                   snap  tmp
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/$ cd opt
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/opt$ ls
riscv
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/opt$ cd riscv/
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/opt/riscv$ ls
bin  include  lib  libexec  riscv32-unknown-elf  share
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/opt/riscv$ cd lib
david@DESKTOP-3UBE0P7:/opt/riscv/lib$ ls
bfd-plugins  gcc  libcc1.la  libcc1.so  libcc1.so.0  libcc1.so.0.0.0  libriscv32-unknown-elf-sim.a
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "run gdb"? Just start `gdb` with no arguments? Attach gdb to a specific executable? If the latter, _check the library dependencies of that executable_. But it'd be much more helpful if you included a _transcript_ in your question so we didn't have to guess at the details of what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, probably a bad description I have given. I've added an EDIT section that might help a bit. But let me know if there are any checks that you advise doing and I will have a go.

Comment: Ahh. (In the future, [please post text, not screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), but that _does_ help). Is there a `libpython3.8.so.1.0` file under `/opt/riscv`, f/e, in `/opt/riscv/lib`? If so, you may just need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include whatever directory that file is in. This is a place where using the `find` command comes in handy: `find /opt/riscv -name 'lib*.so*'` is a good place to start.

Comment: I checked that and edited my question to show you. I don't think the file "libpython3.8.so.1.0" is there.

Comment: I did suggest `find` for a reason -- it'll recurse through the tree instead of only looking in `lib` and ignoring the other options -- but looks like you're probably correct.